# C++/CLI-Question: Is there an equivalent to the C# "is" keyword or do I have to use reflection?

Tags: c++-cli

I've read somewhere on MSDN that the equivalent to C#'s "is" keyword would be dynamic_cast, but that's not really equivalent: It doesn't work with value types or with generic parameters. For example in C# I can write:

```
void MyGenericFunction<T>()
{
    object x = ...
    if (x is T)
        ...;
}
```

If I try the "equivalent" C++/CLI:

```
generic<class T>
void MyGenericFunction()
{
    object x = ...
    if (dynamic_cast<T>(x))
       ...;
}
```

I get a compiler error "error C2682: cannot use 'dynamic_cast' to convert from 'System::Object ^' to 'T'".

The only thing I can think of is to use reflection:

```
if (T::typeid->IsAssignableFrom(obj->GetType()))
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `safe_cast` where you would use `dynamic_cast` in native C++ and trap the System::InvalidCastException. In terms of *compatible types* the semantics of asking if you can convert types could pick up a broader range of types than checking identity. You may actually want the added flexibility of IsAssignableFrom.

I don't think there's an efficient equivalent to the good old `dynamic_cast` idiom we're used to, certainly nothing as compact.

Answer (score 16):

It's on MSDN:

[How to: Implement is and as C# Keywords in C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85af44e9.aspx)

In a nutshell, you need to write a helper function like so:

```
template < class T, class U > 
Boolean isinst(U u) {
   return dynamic_cast< T >(u) != nullptr;
}
```

and call it like this:

```
Object ^ o = "f";
if ( isinst< String ^ >(o) )
    Console::WriteLine("o is a string");
```

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood my question. I know that MSDN article. I mentioned it in my question. And I explained why it doesn't work for me. dynamic_cast isn't equivalent to C# "as". It only works for reference types.

Comment: Oops, should read questions more carefully. It does work for generic types, but not for value types.

Comment: C#'s `as` does not work for value types either: `dynamic_cast` is the exact equivalent of `as`. Use `safe_cast` for casting to value types. The semantics are equivalent to those of C#: throw an exception for bad casts to value types, return `null` for bad casts to reference types.

Answer (score 1):

While a simple workaround would be to use `safe_cast<T>(x)` and catch `System::InvalidCastException^`, this has the obvious overhead of exception handling (unrolling the stack and all the related fun) when the type doesn't match.

I tried to come up with a different approach. While I wouldn't exactly call it *simple*, it does its job without using exceptions.

```
#using <System.Core.dll>

namespace detail
{
    generic <typename T> ref class is_instance_of_managed_helper sealed abstract
    {
    public:
        static initonly System::Func<System::Object^, bool>^ is_instance_of = build();

    private:
        static System::Func<System::Object^, bool>^ build()
        {
            using System::Linq::Expressions::Expression;
            auto param = Expression::Parameter(System::Object::typeid);
            return Expression::Lambda<System::Func<System::Object^, bool>^>(
                Expression::TypeIs(param, T::typeid),
                param)->Compile();
        }
    };

    template <typename T> struct is_instance_of_helper
    {
        static bool is_instance_of(System::Object^ obj)
        {
            return is_instance_of_managed_helper<T>::is_instance_of(obj);
        }
    };

    template <typename T> struct is_instance_of_helper<T^>
    {
        static bool is_instance_of(System::Object^ obj)
        {
            return dynamic_cast<T^>(obj) != nullptr;
        }
    };
}

template <typename T> bool is_instance_of(System::Object^ obj)
{
    return detail::is_instance_of_helper<T>::is_instance_of(obj);
}
```

A bit of explanation:

- `is_instance_of_managed_helper` is a managed class which generates a function at runtime giving the equivalent of C#'s `is` operator. It uses [`Expression::TypeIs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.typeis.aspx) to achieve this in a simple way. One such function will be generated *once* for every `T`.
- `template <typename T> struct is_instance_of_helper` is a template struct which simply uses the above solution. This is the general case.
- `template <typename T> struct is_instance_of_helper<T^>` is a partial specialization of the above struct which uses `dynamic_cast` for managed handle types. This way, we'll spare ourselves the trouble of generating code at runtime when `T` can simply be used with `dynamic_cast`.
- `template <typename T> bool is_instance_of(System::Object^ obj)` is the final helper function which will choose the template to use.