# What is equivalent of C#'s is and as operator in C++/CLI

Tags: c#, c++-cli

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++/CLI-Question: Is there an equivalent to the C# “is” keyword or do I have to use reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712845/c-cli-question-is-there-an-equivalent-to-the-c-is-keyword-or-do-i-have-to-u)

C#'s `is` and `as` operators are not available in C++/CLI environment. What should I use in replace of `is` and `as` in C++/CLI?

Couldn't find duplicate, let me know if there exists one.

Comment: Here's an MSDN article detailing how to implement those operators in C++/CLI: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85af44e9(v=vs.140).aspx