# How do I cast to Interface in C++/CLI?

Tags: .net, casting, c++-cli

I'm having a heck of a time understanding C++/CLI syntax.  I have a member variable defined as so:

```
gcroot<Object^> m_DotNetContextFactory;
```

I'd like to cast this object to an IContextFactory interface.

If I were in C#, I would simply do the following:

```
object contextFactory = ...;
IContextFactory contextFactory = (IContextFactory)contextFactory;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: In managed C++?  Why don't you use C++/CLI instead?

Comment: Forgive me for my ignorance.  I honestly don't know the difference between managed C++ and C++/CLI.  Maybe I am using C++/CLI.  What I have is existing C++/COM code that we're slowly converting to .NET.  For this C++ code that I'm changing, I am converting it to a facade and routing calls to the newer .NET C# components.  Eventually, this C++ class will go away, but for now, we're trying to reduce impact to other COM components dependent on it.  Does that give a little better background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A double cast is required since you rooted Object^.  I assume that's the problem here.  For example:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <msclr\gcroot.h>
using namespace msclr;
using namespace System;

class native {
public:
    gcroot<Object^> m_foo;
};

interface class IBar {};
ref class managed : IBar {};


int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    native* nobj = new native;
    managed^ mobj = gcnew managed;
    nobj->m_foo = mobj;
    IBar^ itf = (IBar^)(Object^)nobj->m_foo;
    return 0;
}
```

Or make it a bit more readable with a helper variable:

```
    Object^ foo = nobj->m_foo;
    IBar^ itf = (IBar^)foo;
```

Comment: Thanks.  That did the trick.  But, don't I have to use gcroot for my member variable?  I thought that is what I read here--http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2005/07/12/Mixing-Native-and-Managed-Types-in-C_2B002B00_.aspx.

Comment: No idea what you're talking about, surely it has nothing to do with casting interfaces?  Start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If you really mean C++/CLI, rather than the obsolete "Managed C++", then I suggest using the safe_cast template as hinted by the following question:

[C++/CLI-Question: Is there an equivalent to the C# "is" keyword or do I have to use reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712845/c-cli-question-is-there-an-equivalent-to-the-c-sharp-is-keyword-or-do-i-hav)