# how to find out type of Control on Form in VC++ 2010

Tags: winforms, visual-c++

i need to find out the Type of control on the form. is it a TreeView, GroupBox or a Label

i am using

```
for(int i=0;i!=Properties->Controls->Count;i++)
{
   Control^ Current_Control=Properties->Controls->default[i];
}
```

sorry for my English

Comment: array<String^>^ Control_Type_Name=Properties->Controls->default[i]->GetType()->FullName->Split('.');


String^ Control_Type=Control_Type_Name[Control_Type_Name->Length-1];

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++/CLI-Question: Is there an equivalent to the C# "is" keyword or do I have to use reflection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712845/c-cli-question-is-there-an-equivalent-to-the-c-sharp-is-keyword-or-do-i-hav)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through the controls on the form and use TypeOf and GetType:

```
    Public Sub ClearAll(ByVal frm As Control)
    For Each C As Control In frm.Controls
        Dim Ctl As Control = C
        If ControlList.Contains(Ctl.GetType) Then
            ClearAll(Ctl)
        ElseIf (TypeOf Ctl Is TextBox) Then
            Ctl.Text = ""
        End If   
    Next
   End Sub
```

This searches for the TextBox and clears the text. If it hits groupbox or other container it clears all the textboxes within it.